# Remove and Track Items Bought and Returned

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which records all the transaction details for items. The format looks like the following columns:

- Item
- Transaction Type (Sale, Purchase, Vendor Return,Sales Return)
- Change Description (detail along with OrderNumber)
- Quantity Added
- Quantity Subtracted

I am trying to get the Last Purchase Date, and the Last Sale Date which was not returned. For example a purchase was made on OrderNumber 1256 on May 15, 2015 for 144 Items and the next day there is a Transaction for a return on OrderNumber 1256. I'm not sure how I can approach this. Would I create another column which has Returned (True or False) and then update that depending on if there was a return associated to this? 
Would this be achieved via stored procedure or a simple query?

Here is the sample data:

```
Item   TransactionDate TransactionType ChangeDescription            AdditionQty    SubtractionQty
1006     2015-05-27    VENDOR RETURN       RETURN NO. 423      0             -144
1006     2015-05-28    PURCHASE            PURCH NO. 423              144               0
```

So When I am pulling up the Last Purchase Date, this would essentially be removed because this was purchased but returned.

Comment: Add a net balance column, then you can just select the most recent row where it isn't 0.

Comment: Could there be a case where you set AddQty and SubQty both? Wouldn't it be easier to have one single column?

Comment: Please provide the declaration of all tables involved!

Comment: Is the purchase no. really stored in the description and not in a separate column?

Comment: You mentioned a `OrderNumber` in your question, but the sample data doesn't provide a column with this name?

Comment: You sure about that sample data?   "Battery" is a TransactionDate?   "2015-05-27" is a TransactionType?

Comment: I have edited the table. Please take a look again.
Yes the Number is recorded in a description. I wouldn't do it that way but that's how it is. 
No I have not come across a case where the AddQty and SubQty would both have values.The order Number is in the Change Description.

Comment: Does ChangeDescription start with SALE if it is a sale?

Comment: Yes It does. 
The other approach I was thinking was to create a temp table to store all Transactions that Have the OrderNumber >1 meaning that its either a return/Sales or return/Purchase.  Then I can use that within my exclude those records.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood and you have an order number in item, this could be what you are looking for; of course with more info it could be easier ...

```
SELECT Item, LastPurchaseDate
FROM (
   SELECT Item, MAX(TransactionDate) LastPurchaseDate, SUM(AdditionQty) AdditionQty, SUM(SubtractionQty) SubtractionQty
   FROM Table
   GROUP BY Item ) A
WHERE (A.AdditionQty + A.SubtractionQty) != 0
```

Comment: This did not work. I still see the last Purchase date as the last time that item was bout (as shown above).

Comment: I made a fake table on SQLFiddle and it seems to be working... Please check it and tell me if it fits on your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80850/1

Comment: Did you check? Any news?

Answer (score 0):

Using a temp table:

```
select Item, TransactionDate, LEFT(ChangeDescription,3) as TransType, RIGHT(a.ChangeDescription,LEN(a.ChangeDescription)-(CHARINDEX('.',a.ChangeDescription) + 1) as OrderNo
into #temp
from [table]

SELECT a.Item,MAX(a.TransactionDate),a.TransType,a.OrderNo
FROM #temp a
INNER JOIN #temp b
ON a.OrderNo = b.OrderNo AND a.TransType <> b.TransType
GROUP BY a.TransType
```